# wrong value is being inserted into the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$min_year = 1;
$max_year = 10;
$years = range($min_year, $max_year); // returns array with numeric values of 1900 - 2012
$yearHTML = '';
$yearHTML .= '<select name="year" id="yearDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$yearHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
foreach ($years as $year) {
    if (!$validSubmission && isset($_POST['year']) && $year == $_POST['year'])
    {
        $yearHTML .= "<option value='".$year."' selected='selected'>$year</option>".PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        $yearHTML .= "<option value='".$year."'>$year</option>".PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$yearHTML .= '</select>';
```

Above I have a drop down menu which consists of options 1 - 10 in the drop down menu. The problem I am having is that no matter which number I select from the drop down menu, it keeps inserting the number `1` in the database. Can anybody see why in the code below why it is doing this:

```
$getyear = in_array($_POST['year'], $years);

    $insertsql = "
    INSERT INTO Student
    (Year)
    VALUES
    (?)
    ";
    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }                                           

    $insert->bind_param("i", $getyear);

    $insert->execute();

    if ($insert->errno) {
    // Handle query error here
    }

    $insert->close();
```

Comment: You should check what `$getyear` is being set to - `in_array()` returns a boolean value, which is being converted to a 1 when it's true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$getyear = in_array($_POST['year'], $years);
```

returns TRUE. True is cast to INT, so becomes 1;

Replace by:

```
if( in_array($_POST['year'], $years) === true ){
  $getyear = (int) $_POST['year'];
}
```

Comment: That makes sure it returns true, and not something else. I call it good practice.

Comment: See [PHP: Comparison Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), where it states that for $a === $b, it is TRUE if $a is equal to $b, **and they are of the same type**.

Comment: `in_array` always returns a boolean so there's no need to explicitly check for boolean.

Comment: @jmgardn2 I know what `===` _does_. I was asking what is it doing _here_.

Comment: @JanDvorak, sorry misunderstood. In that case, John brings up a good point, just a good habit to have.

Comment: Well, it is a preference. I think it makes the code more readable and more fail proof. If you use another function that may return a string (like: string "Error" (== true)), you always do it the right way because you used to do it like this.